# Apache NameVirtualHost and multiple hostnames

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualization

I'd like to use one VirtualServer for both www.example.com and example.com. Is this possible? Can I at least have one reference another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ServerAlias` directive:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAlias foo.example.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```